# Add 30 days in date

Tags: bash, mysql, date

Using `bash` or `mysql` , how can I add **30** days in user `expiry` table?

Example I have DB name `USERS` and table `expiry` like this:

```
USERNAME   EXPIRATION
JOHN       2015-09-26
```

I want the command to take whatever value is in `EXPIRATION` column for a specified `USERNAME` and add **30** days to it

So the result would be:

```
USERNAME   EXPIRATION
JOHN       2015-10-26
```

Comment: `SELECT DATE_ADD(date_field, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS dd FROM table`

Comment: @taliezin
sorry for providing less information. Now I have updated the Question again. Thank you for time.

Comment: maybe like this
`select DATE_ADD(expiration, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS dd from rm_users where username= 'quotauser2';`

Comment: Please include the output of `describe the-table;`

Answer (score 17):

Using GNU `date` :

```
$ date -d '2015-09-26 +30 days' '+%Y-%m-%d'
2015-10-26
```

Comment: For `'+%Y-%m-%d'` short substitution is `-I` option

Answer (score 2):

Here a example for date output as ISO-8601 format one month from now:

```
date -I -d '+1 month'
```

Comment: One month is not always 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BSD (or another system that uses the BSD POSIX, like macOS), you can still use `date` like this:

```bsh
$ date -v+30d -jnf %Y-%m-%d "2015-09-26" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: Thank you! This fit my need of 30 days from today's date on macOS: `date -v+30d +%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL's `date_add()` function in an `UPDATE` statement, updating the entry for `JOHN`. This would *update* the data in the table.

```
UPDATE TABLE USERS
SET EXPIRATION = date_add(EXPIRATION, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
WHERE USERNAME = "JOHN"
```

To just select the the data and increment it for display purposes,

```
SELECT USERNAME, date_add(EXPIRATION, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS "EXPIRATION" FROM USERS
WHERE USERNAME = "JOHN"
```